# Hibernate uses @JoinColumn as sequence name instead of table name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-envers

Recently migrated to spring boot 3 and have run into the following issue.

```java
@Audited
@Entity
class ParentEntity {
...
@NotAudited
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trace_info_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private TraceInfo traceInfo;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "trace_infos")
public class TraceInfo extends IDEntity {
...
}
```

```java
@Audited(
    targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED
)
public class IDEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}
```

When I try to insert a record into ParentEntity class, hibernate looks for a sequence called  `trace_infos_seq`, and cant find it. On startup the sequence it generates is called `trace_info_id_seq`. Is this expected behavior? How do I get it to look for the correct sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have defined a `@OneToOne` relationship between `ParentEntity` and `TraceInfo` using the `@JoinColumn` annotation. The `@JoinColumn` annotation specifies the name of the foreign key column in the owning entity's table that is used to establish the relationship.

When you use `@JoinColumn(name = "trace_info_id")`, Hibernate understands that this column is a foreign key referencing the `TraceInfo` entity. However, **Hibernate does not generate a sequence name based on the foreign key column name**. Instead, it generates the sequence name based on the identifier column of the referenced entity (`TraceInfo` in this case).

Since the identifier column of `TraceInfo` is `id`, Hibernate generates a sequence named `trace_info_id_seq` by default. This is why you're observing the behavior you mentioned.

To resolve this issue, you can explicitly specify the sequence name using the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation on the `TraceInfo` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "trace_infos")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "traceInfoSeq", sequenceName = "trace_info_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class TraceInfo extends IDEntity {
    // ... your entity code here ...
}
```

By adding the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation to the `TraceInfo` entity, you're instructing Hibernate to use the specified sequence name (`trace_info_id_seq`) for generating identifiers for the `TraceInfo` entity.

Check this out:

- [SequenceGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/id/SequenceGenerator.html)
- [JoinColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)

Comment: This seems to work for one of my environments but not for the other, ive tried deleting the pgsql schema but it still wont generate the new sequence, is there a cache somewhere that I need to clear?

Comment: If the sequence generation is working in one environment but not in another, it's possible that there might be some differences in the database configuration or schema.